# How to integrate user permissions/restrictions for Hibernate queries?

Tags: hibernate, security, permissions, lucene, spring-security

I am using Spring Security in my java Web application with Hibernate to get data from the database.  We are now at the point where we need to restrict what results the user can retrieve based on what page they are on and what access level they have.  I.E.

For page One, and admin can see all, a manager can see/search for everything with attribute **A** where the value is *X* and site manager can only see/search for everything on that page with attribute **B** is the value *Y*.

Currently we use a poorly written HQL function that pieces together a string query based on the user and location passed in.  It is a VERY large `If...Else if....else...if else` etc.

I was trying to fix this by doing it in a more programatic manner with the Hibernate FullTextFilter annotations.  However I would need to search on a **join table** by an attribute of one of the primary keys, which I don't think would work too well.

***What is the best practice/recommended way of getting items from the database based on greatly varying permissions?***

Comment: Did you come up with a proper solution about this issue you were having at that time ? I'm facing this exact same issue and can't find another way than hardcoding the "where" clause with if statements like you describe in your question.

Comment: Sorry this was so long ago I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

Since your users have roles you can use spring security annotations on service layer(preferably) to secure those methods from getting called from users without permission. in you views you can use spring security jsp tags to hide items that they will not have access.
[spring security jsp tag](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html),
[to secure urls and methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)
so if in your jsp page you want to hide something(where only user with role supervisor can see) it will be similar like this(depending on your needs)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">

This content will only be visible to users who have
the "supervisor" authority in their list of <tt>GrantedAuthority</tt>s.

</sec:authorize>
```

as well as you can define what type of users can invoke methods like this:

```
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
  public void create(Contact contact);
```

Go over the documentation you should be able to achieve what you are trying to do by using this libraries.

Hope it helps.

Comment: We actually use the `<sec:authorize>` tags for the **tables** that differ between user roles.  However many of the elements are seen by **all users** it is only **which records in the database they can access** that differs. So when the tables are initially populated we use hibernate `FullTextFilters` to populate the tables with the correct rows.  However now when searching on the tables we ***also need to restrict the search results based on the permissions***.

Comment: After reading a bit it sounds like **creating separate indexes for individual roles** is the preferred option.  Although it probably wouldn't work for this situation as the access roles aren't really static, nice/neat sets.

Comment: well i guess i would not know how to do it without static roles

Comment: They are technically static roles, its just that the role doesn't specify "Role X can only see records A,B,C" but rather its more like "Role X can see any records where **attribute** A equals **B and C**" and the role specifies what that attribute should equal.  So naturally it just seems like having a "Select ...Where" HQL statement would be best, but concatenating all those strings for the different situations is very unwieldy and messy.

Comment: well that does not require a lot if else if statements, rather it could be done via joins. example with named native query-> select * from someTable t,otherTable o where t.a = o.b and t.a = o.c and t=:tvalue . Then you do Query query = session.getNamedQuery("nameofNamedQuery").setString("tvalue","somevalue");